# How can the "single scroll" arrows be added to OSX Mavericks Terminal windows, et. al.?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, mouse, scrolling

Is there another solution to this problem using `X`, perhaps maybe a setting in the window managers `twm` and/or `quartz-wm`?  We've looked at the usual `xterm` settings, and cannot recall how we once set it up to scroll at a page set to a single line at a time.  Is there such a thing? I think we once set this up in `XEmacs` under `mwm`.  Is there a Mavericks OSX equivalent?

Presently, we like to set our `bash` histories to 10,000 lines and `Terminal`'s settings to scroll back limited only by availably memory, and frequently, `Terminal`'s scroll buffer gets LARGE; it gets ridiculously hard to grab the scrollbar slider with the mouse and make fine adjustments.  I've resorted to either using gestures with my lefthand on the MBP trackpad and/or using Ubuntu running on Parallels just to get that environment's `Terminal` interface - it's hard to snapshot that, because the control "dissolves" quickly before I can select it.  :-)

There's got to be a more elegant solution!

Please help - I've checked all *the usual suspects* for a solution for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**More on *the usual suspects*:**

Got `gnome-terminal` running in Mavericks `XQuartz`. The things that were tried were Ubuntu's `Terminal` running in a Parallel's VM, using `XEmacs`'s `shell` `minor-mode`, and finding a way to get `X` to load a `window manager` that provides that `widget`.  All these approaches were not satisfactory solutions.  Fortunately, `FinkCommander` already had the `gnome-terminal` distribution bundled and ready to compile on Mavericks - note, however, some contention with `brew`, as described in the next paragraph.

The problem with this approach is that we use `brew` to install our open source, and `FinkCommander` and `brew` **DO NOT** coexist well together.  Each have strong points, and in this case, `brew` does not have formulae for the `gnome` tools we want, and `fink` does, so the follow-on to this topic is how to use both `brew` (installs to `/usr/local`) and `fink` (installs to `/sw`) at the same time?  Having one or the other in the path when working with the other causes problems, both with compiling the toolsets and with using them, hence, the new topic.

Here is a picture of my `gnome-terminal` - notice the up and down-arrows on the windows right edge at the top and bottom of the scrollbar?  This is the best solution available to this problem..

[image: <code>gnome-terminal</code>]